Flutter dart null safety
I am trying to install firebase_firestore flutter plugin but I am getting the following error:
flutter pub add firebase_firestore
The current Dart SDK version is 3.5.3.

Because mpolice depends on firebase_firestore any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=1.8.0 <2.0.0-dev.infinity'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

My pubspec is the following:
name: mpolice
description: "Ap"
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.3 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.8
  intl: ^0.19.0
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.5.3
  firebase_core: ^3.4.0
  firebase_auth: ^5.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^5.0.0

I am not being able to find this sdk range nowhere and my pubspec's lower bound is already higher than 2.19.0. WHere is this message coming from?

Is it perhaps cloud_firestore that you should install?

It says mpolice

you are right! @RobertSandberg I misread firebase tutorial. Thank you!

I think you want to switch to cloud_firestore with FlutterFire from the firebase_core package. I believe firebase_firestore was deprecated after Dart 1 so you need to update to firebase_core and cloud_firestore.
You can check for null safe packages using
dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety

But I believe the packages of firestore and firebase should be the packages you need. FlutterFire has the documentation on this, and all these packages are null-safe. You can also see in the version tab on any dart package whether they are null-safe.
